# Show that one combination is more likely than others.

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, correlation

I have 2 variables shape X and size Y.
Shape $X$ has 4 states ($x_{0}, x_1, x_2, x_3$) and size $Y$ has 3 states ($y_0, y_1, y_2$).

The contingency table could look like this:

| Y \ X | $x_0$ | $x_1$ | $x_2$ | $x_3$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $y_0$ | 350 | 50 | 40 | 0 |
| $y_1$ | 100 | 150 | 50 | 50 |
| $y_2$ | 10 | 90 | 10 | 5 |

How can I show that one combination ($x_0 / y_0$) is significantly likelier that the others?
What is the correct "statistical" way to do that?
Do I need the correlation coefficient for that?

Can I just say the probability that shape $x_0$ has size $y_0$ is $350/(350+50+40) = 0.795$ and that probability is higher than that for any other shape/size combination?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited the post. I hope my problem is presented more clearly now.

Comment: Even now, I think it is not clear. Option 1 : For one shape, we have many sizes, and we want to know if a specific size is significantly more frequent than the others , and we will repeat this question for each shape, and probably find 'Yes' for some shapes, and 'no' for other shapes. Option 2 : same , but switch shape and size. Option 3 : we have 12 values, and we want to know if one value is significantly higher than the 11 other values. In both cases, I think the correct keyword for you is 'test statistic unilateral' (not sure)

Comment: I'm mostly going for the 3rd option.
Could I do a one-sample Wilcoxon test to conclude that 350 is significantly greater than the other values?

Comment: You cannot derive _*any*_ statistical conclusions about the data, unless you know how it was collected. Assuming this was a simple random sample, then you should be able to use a $z$-test to refute the null hypothesis that the probability of $(x_0,y_0)$ is $1/12$.  Please edit your question to include this necessary context.